# Cannot `brew install` from a `bash` script

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew

I want to create a script to setup an environment on a Mac. Here's a simple sample...

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
brew install gcovr || exit 1
gcovr --version
```

> ***NOTE:** Script assumes `brew` was previously installed .*

When I execute the script I get an error.

```
$ ./install
Warning: gcovr 4.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 4.1, run `brew reinstall gcovr`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/gcovr/4.1/libexec/bin/gcovr", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

However, if I run it directly from the command line, it progresses as expected.

```
$ brew install gcovr
Warning: gcovr 4.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 4.1, run `brew reinstall gcovr`
```

It should be noted, the script does install `gcovr` before failing and bailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this error comes from Python being misconfigured.

The answer is to `brew postinstall python3`.

When Googling around, I found a separate project demonstrating a [similar issue](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema/issues/260).

Here is what I saw on my machine:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

```
$ brew install python
Warning: python 3.7.4 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link python` to link this version.
```

```
$ brew postinstall python3
==> Postinstalling python
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install
```

After running `postinstall`, it didn't appear to change Python

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

However, it did postively affect Homebrew, and allowed the script to run successfully!

```
$ ./install
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
No changes to formulae.

Warning: gcovr 4.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 4.1, run `brew reinstall gcovr`
gcovr 4.1

Copyright 2013-2018 the gcovr authors
Copyright 2013 Sandia Corporation
Under the terms of Contract DE-AC04-94AL85000 with Sandia Corporation,
the U.S. Government retains certain rights in this software.
```